# Why does 'echo *' give different results than 'ls *'?

Tags: ls, echo, wildcards

For example, if you are in home directory and type `ls *`, you will have all the directories listed, and below the name of the listed directory, the files that it contains. On the other hand, if you type `echo *` the command will list just the directories, and not the directories and content that they have. Why is that?

Comment: because `echo` and `ls` are not the same.

Answer (score 6):

In both cases the `*` gets expanded by the shell.

`echo` than just prints the parameters resulting from the expansion.

`ls` checks for every parameter if it is a directory and lists its contents if it is one.